# Questions tagged with Boost and ASIO should be retagged to Boost.ASIO

Tags: discussion, retag-request

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asio+boost

ASIO is [a software interface for audio applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Stream_Input/Output).  Boost.ASIO is a network library.  They're not the same thing.

Comment: Is there a consideration for ASIO libraries that are not boost?

Comment: @MatthewLundberg: Except for sound drivers, there aren't any other such libraries, except maybe [this one](http://think-async.com/)

Comment: I'd also like to note the *"unsourced material, may be removed"* notice on the Wikipedia page for ASIO. Please don't take freely editable pages for granted. I personally am highly suspicious regarding this protocol and its notability/importance, while Boost.Asio is a famous and proven technology.

Comment: @ulidtko ASIO is used in _all_ digital audio workstations on Windows, it's highly notable.

Comment: Soon enough there will be one in TR2: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2054.pdf.  In addition, systems have had asych networking for a long time; in the past they were not abbreviated with this particular four-letter acronym, but in the future, they probably all will be.

Comment: @ulidtko: Nobody has a quarrel with Boost.ASIO having its own tag.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, well, agreed. But then again, the `asio` tag wiki must mention boost.asio and give tagging instructions. I'll go make a revision.

Comment: @ulidtko: ASIO only means asynchronous IO in the context of BOOST libraries.

Comment: @NmdMystery care to improve the Wikipedia article by providing notability references?

Comment: @ulidtko [The boost ASIO page is looking pretty skimpy as well.  Maybe Wikipedia isn't a good reference for notability of software libraries.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asio_C%2B%2B_library)

Comment: Maybe not, but Google is.  Notability of an article in Google is defined (more or less) by how many significant pages on the Internet link to it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't know why we're still on notability, though.  I just want to be able to find relevant questions dammit.

Comment: @NmdMystery: We're on notability because people are trying to make ASIO into a "thing," and I don't think it's a thing at all.  But Steinberg's ASIO standard is definitely a thing, and it has nothing to do with Boost or network communication.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Agreed, but none of this matters because the number of questions regarding ASIO is greater than one.

Comment: What are you getting at?  If the number of questions were zero, we wouldn't even be having this nice conversation.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I mean that I'm not the only one asking about ASIO, thus it's notable enough to be its own category, end of story.  This wiki is supposed to serve all its users, after all - even those inquiring about an obscure concept (if it's not already given that ASIO _isn't_ at all obscure) - not just most of them.  The fact that ASIO has few questions asked about it is actually all the more reason to include it, since more new information will be made available.

Comment: @NmdMystery: If you can demonstrate that [BOOST.ASIO] will not solve the problem, I'll drop my argument.  But so far, the arguments posed for having [ASIO] as a generic tag for asynchronous IO don't seem all that compelling to me, given that ASIO already has a specific, well-known meaning to audio programmers.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm just saying that notability isn't contributing to the discussion, I'm not arguing against you (in fact I agree with you).  (PS if you forgot I'm the guy that posted the question that spawned this issue.  I'm talking about the audio interface any time I use the term ASIO).

Answer (score 4):

I disagree. The *common understanding* of a plain "asio" is **asynchronous IO**, in case of C++ directly associated with the Boost library, but not necessarily relating to it. It may mean other Reactor-based frameworks/libraries, such as Java NIO, or future libraries of similar designs.

Out of the 50 top voted questions tagged with `asio` right now 49 are about asynchronous I/O, and 1 is about the sound protocol.

---

In case if the tag rename will be accepted and implemented, I'd like to see a reference to `Boost.Asio` from the ASIO tag wiki and excerpt, probably with disambiguation instructions.

Comment: Do the 49 that you're referring to also have the Boost tag?

Comment: Well, yes, most of them do.

Comment: While boost is (currently) the most popular C++ ASIO implementation, note that ASIO predates boost.  By a few decades.

Comment: The description of the asio tag should be changed and ASIO should be given its own tag if this is the case, since it otherwise has none.  Right now the asio tag refers to this interface, not asynchronous I/O.

Comment: @NmdMystery: Someone already changed the [ASIO tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/asio/info) 15 minutes ago.  If ASIO is really a thing, beyond the music software interface, then so be it, but I don't know if I like the idea of one tag having multiple meanings.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Agreed.  The new description doesn't help the issue we're having in the first place, which is the fact that searches for questions about the ASIO audio interface are turning up completely unrelated results.

Comment: I am the tag wiki changer. The previous definition has surprised me a lot, so I augmented it.  Community has approved my edit.

Comment: Note that http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Stream_Input/Output is the first search result in a Google search for ASIO.  Boost.ASIO is its own thing, and deserves its own tag.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, in my results, the first one leads to www.asio.gov.au, an Australian intelligence organisation. So maybe that's not a good indicator.

Comment: We don't care about that.  You can disregard any results that don't have anything to do with software.

Comment: @ulidtko I don't know whether or not it's even necessary to provide a tag for asynchronous I/O, since you could just tag a question "threads" and "IO" or something like that and get more views anyway.  If just for completion, I'd still hang on to my previous idea.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg: References, please.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Quick example, System Services in VMS.  See here for an example in C: http://h71000.www7.hp.com/doc/82final/6529/6529pro_002.html (see example 6.2).

Comment: @MatthewLundberg: ASIO is not even mentioned on that page.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Due to boost, the acronym ASIO has come to mean "asynchronous input/output" to many programmers.  See my comment to the question above.  The VMS System Services predate the acronym, but I'd not be surprised to see an ASIO tag on a question about `sys$qio`.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg: In other words, it's all about Boost.  Ergo, Boost.ASIO.  We can't make tags based on what we think they *might* mean in the future, and it doesn't mean that today because Google says it doesn't.

Comment: Not *only* about Boost. Here's a [Java ASIO](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasio/) library which has nothing to do with Boost, and C++ as well.

Comment: @ulidtko 0 downloads.

Comment: @RobertHarvey but it fact, future is not needed: exactly the thing described by Matthew happened in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3741611)! The OP asked about "ASIO" meaning right that, async IO, — apparently without even knowing about Boost. Then, NmdMystery wiped out the tag from the question. That's not fair.

Comment: @ulidtko: How about [asio-async-io] and [asio-audio]?

Comment: @RobertHarvey [asio-audio] looks like a fit to me. Although a question stays on what to to with [asio] — a disambiguation page?

Comment: We don't have disambiguation pages.  The pastiche tags would both show up any time someone typed "asio" into the tags field.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Looks good to me as long as the use of [asio] is banned, otherwise people will just use plain asio all the time.

Comment: [asio] would be synonymized to one of the other tags (probably the audio one since, y'know, it is the most common use of the term)

Comment: @ulidtko That's pretty much the only case in which it happened, though.  The majority of asio posts are coupled with boost.  If we're talking about a consensus then it seems to me that the consensus is that asio is primarily related to boost-asio.  I'd still go with retagging both as Robert suggested.

Comment: @NmdMystery, still, it's further evidence that asio is "a thing" in network programming, not perfectly synonymous with the highest quality library implementing it. So we have just a plain term conflict.

Comment: @ulidtko As much as I find this aspect irrelevant to the issue, we're attempting to define ASIO by its meaning in common lingo.  IE, if few people are using it on its own to mean asynchronous I/O, then it's not a common term, even if it _can_ mean that.  Not to mention, Audio Stream Input/Output only has one name, ASIO.  It's a specific brand.  You can call asynchronous I/O by several other terms.  You can even make up your own.  Pragmatically, the asio tag serves the audio interface more than the general concept of asynchronous IO programming.  That's pretty much the summary of my view here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sorry for reviving this, but I just realized that ASIO doesn't even stand for Asyncronous IO.  That would be AIO.  What's the S for?  [AIO even has its own tag that literally means what ulidtko claims ASIO means](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/aio/info).  After finding that, I think that asynchronous IO should be delegated to [aio] instead, and Audio Stream Input/Output own the [asio] tag.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Also it seems like asio as a term referring to asynchronous I/O originated from [this library, which eventually became boost::asio.](http://think-async.com/)  The author(s) don't really provide a reason why it's called Asio and not Aio, which is a little confusing.