# Replace [asio] tag with [audio-asio]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

The [asio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asio) tag is described as the ASIO professional audio I/O, but most questions use it as [boost-asio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost-asio).

I suggest to replace it with [audio-asio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio-asio) or something like that.

Comment: [asio] has been on my checklist for a long time now, related posts 1. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339380/steinberg-asio-is-all-noise 2. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253796/questions-tagged-with-boost-and-asio-should-be-retagged-to-boost-asio. This isn't simple, but I'm open to opinions as to how we can solve the entire problem with ASIO, Steinberg ASIO and Boost ASIO